# Como o navegador google etc faz isso?

Tags: google-chrome

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso criar um esquema de url similar ao chrome e outros browsers etc?
Quero fazer com que o arquivo .html abra nesse esquema de url, assim como se fosse file://.
Em vez disso eu quero algo como new://index.html. 
Quero abrir arquivos locais usando esse esquema de url.

Comment: Não sei se serve para o seu caso, mas pode procurar por "navigator.registerProtocolHandler" disponível a partir do chrome 13

Comment: Olha essa [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so) fala sobre criar um protocolo, tipo `ftp://`...etc

Comment: Ja adianto que cada OS tem um jeito de associar um handler a um URI SCHEME. Por exemplo, no Windows, é uma simples entrada de registro https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx