# Como funciona a abertura do Utorrent pelo navegador

Tags: javascript, c#, aplicação-web, navegador-de-internet

Olá, eu pretendo criar um programa que quando for chamado pelo navegador, ele abra o programa e execute suas funções, parecido como o utorrent faz. Realizei algumas pesquisas mas não encontrei nada até o momento e não sei a forma correta de se pesqusiar.

Edit: Randrade, exatamente isso que eu procurava, estou criando uma aplicação web que será necessário chamar uma aplicação que vai estar instalada no computador do cliente, porém eu não sabia o nome do recurso para conseguir implantar.
O que preciso é realmente o Custom URL protocol.

Aproveitando gostaria de complementar a pergunta, utilizando o Custom URL protocol é possível enviar parâmetros para a aplicação?

Comment: Isto é configuração do navegador, nada tem a ver com programação.

Comment: Davy, por acaso o que você busca seria um [Custom URL Protocol](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332206/Custom-URL-Protocol-for-Invoking-Application)? Caso seja isso mesmo, [neste link você encontra um tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page) de como implementar algo parecido. Lembrando que você sempre pode [edit] a sua pergunta e colocar mais detalhe para ficar mais fácil de compreender e te ajudarmos.

Comment: Aproveitando, que tal fazer o [tour] para conhecer melhor o site?

Comment: @Randrade se for isso, creio que é dup desta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210534/70 (e é ampla, vide comentário que eu fiz na original)